# Magento 1.9 Change Layout Columns

Tags: magento

I want to change the "`/checkout/onepage/success/`" layout from 
2-Colunms with a left Aside Block to a 1-Column-layout.

I tried to change it in:

```
app/design/frontend/base/layout/checkout.xml

app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/checkout.xml
```

but nothing changed. Yes I've cleared the cache!

In Backend "System -> Configuration -> Design -> Actual Package" "**rwd**" is in use" Translation, Layout, Skin are empty. Standard is "default".

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

In your rwd theme go to this path ' ***/frontend/rwd/default/layout/checkout.xml*** '

Find the ' ***checkout_onepage_success*** ' section  and replase

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
```

To

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
```

Solve your problem....Simple.